# Implicit type inferring with function arguments in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I have `map` function:

```
const map = <T, U>(f: (x: T) => U, arr: T[]): U[] => {
  return arr.map((val) => f(val));
}
```

When I'm calling `map` with anonymous function as a callback, it's return type is correct:

```
// `x1` variable type here is { name: string }[], which is correct
const x1 = map(x => x, [{name: 'John'}]);
```

But when I'm providing `identity` function instead of anonymous one, return type is wrong:

```
const identity = <T>(x: T) => x
// return type of `x2` is {}[] here
const x2 = map(identity, [{name: 'John'}]);
```

How to get correct type result for 2nd example, without providing explicit type arguments for `map` function?

Comment: What if you specify the return type as `T` on `identity`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe the same result..

Comment: It works fine if you switch the order of `map()`'s arguments.  I guess it forces the compiler to match the array element type first? I don't know if there's a way to get the inference to work in the order you have.

Comment: @jcalz nice find! I'll think on it, big thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some trying, I honestly doubt TypeScript is able to follow you that far.
For example:

```
const x4 = map(identity, [2]);
// x4 is '{}[]'
```

which is obviosly even more wrong than your example.

Some other tests:

```
const x2 = map(<({ name: string }) => { name: string }>identity, [{ name: 'John' }]);
// x2 is '{ name: string }[]'
```

And:

```
const double = (x: number) => 2 * x;
const x3 = map(double, [2]);
// x3 is 'number[]'
```

This lets me conclude that TypeScript just can't break all that generics down to a meaningful type and just says *{}*.